# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\Article::categories()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on my Laravel project, and have a problem with many-to-many relationship
it throws back the following error:

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\Article::categories()

although I have defined the relationship as categories in my Article model, Laravel solution is:
*Bad Method Call Did you mean App\Models\Article::categories()?*

Please help me to find out which part of code could lead to this issue

Article Model:
[image: Article Model]

Article Controller:
[image: Article Controller]

Category Controller:
[image: Category Controller]

Comment: Please provide your code in the question and not as separate images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `categories` method in the `Article` model is protected. To access it like you intend it needs to be declared as `public`.

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: public function scopeKadwal($query)
    {
        return $query->where('id',1);
    }

$share = Share::kadwal()->get();

error: Bad Method Call
Did you mean App\Models\Share::scopeKadwal() ?

I am encountering this error from last days, I tried several ways but it seems does working

Comment: Please open a separate question for your problem. It is entirely unrelated to my answer.